# Are there any tools to detect buffer overflow on Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been having crash problems due to heap problems, so I guess a buffer overflow is happening somewhere. How do I detect it?

Comment: "heap problems" are far from synonymous with "buffer oberflow"

Comment: They aren't synonyms, certainly, but heap problems are a likely symptom of buffer overruns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Compuware BoundsChecker](http://www.compuware.com/products/devpartner/visualc.htm) as a tool for error detection in VC6. It can pick up buffer overruns.

You can also try [PageHeap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470), a tool for windows.

Comment: I had some problems trying to use PageHeap, this question defines them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781821/debug-visual-c-memory-allocation-problems Could you provide more info on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Rational Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VC debug heap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx

Most if not all of the stuff in crtdbg.h is also supported in VC6.

Answer (score 0):

I got good results when simply inserting _heapchk() Windows API function on some places and hunt the error (a access to index -1 to an array in my case).