# Domino Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Error: nHTTP.EXE

Tags: lotus-domino

This error has occurred twice today on our development server running Domino 8.5.3:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40159/DominoDebugError.png

When this happens it slows HTTP to a crawl and we have to reboot the server. Anyone have any ideas of why this may be happening or ways to prevent? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793375/what-could-cause-damage-after-normal-block-error), it looks like there is memory corruption occurring in the Domino server's HTTP task.  If you don't have any custom or 3rd-party add-ons running on the server that might have caused this, then it would appear to be an IBM problem and you should call them for support.

Comment: We are using the Extension Library on the server. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just to be sure... Extension Manager (i.e., code written in the Notes C API hooking server events), or Extension Library (i.e., code provided by OpenNTF and IBM to enhance the Domino server's XPages programmability)?

Comment: Then it definitely sounds like an IBM problem to me.  The only strange thing IMHO is that you're getting the VC++ error dialog instead of it crashing and generating an NSD file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any UTF-8 file handling in Lotusscript ?
If you are beware if the files is not in UTF-8 format then you will get a memory corruption.

Comment: No. I don't believe we are doing any UTF-8 handling.